# Heat transfer with surroundings: why considered reversible?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, energy, entropy

I do not understand how the fact that the surroundings are large makes heat transfer with them reversible? I understand that the temperature of the surroundings is not going to change in the limit, but what about processes in which there is a definite temperature gradient with the system, such as a highly exothermic reaction?

I was sure that this question had already been asked somewhere on Stack, but I can't find anything similar – if you know of one, I would really appreciate if you could refer me to it.

Answer (score 2):

The surroundings are typically modelled in thermodynamics as an ideal (reversible) reservoir with infinite heat capacity and negligible temperature gradients (i.e., infinite thermal conductivity).  The assumption is that the temperature gradients are confined to the system, rather than the surroundings, and the entropy generation is confined to the system.  Of course, in real life, this is only an approximation.

Comment: Thank you! So for example, if you burn something, do you consider the burning material and the shell of hot air it generates as the "system", and put the boundary between the system and the surroundings where the temperature difference between the air inside the shell and the air outside it becomes infinitesimal?

Comment: Sorry, how do I reference your name? @Chester Miller and any variations aren't recognised.

Comment: Apparently it did.

Comment: No.  The temperature difference at the boundary is always infinitesimal.  Temperature is continuous at a boundary.  I'm not talking about an interface with air outside the shell, but with an ideal reservoir (e.g. a liquid) featuring an infinite heat capacity and infinite thermal conductivity.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused. So you're assuming that no temperature gradients with the surroundings can exist in principle, e.g. when something is burning, any heat released is instantly absorbed by the surroundings with infinite thermal conductivity? In this case I don't see how this can be a good assumption?

Comment: Or does our definition of the surroundings changes as the surroundings absorb heat (i.e. from a thin shell of surroundings approximately at the same temp as the system, to infinity?)

Comment: In most cases in thermodynamics books, heat transfer to the surroundings is regarded as taking place using an ideal constant temperature bath/reservoir.

Comment: Thanks! But when applied to real systems, what corrections need to be made and how to make them? The assumption of the reversible heat transfer with the surroundings seems to be at the very core of thermodynamics, so you would probably need to correct for almost every step? Perhaps you know any theoretical treatments of situations where heat gradients with the surroundings are significant?

Comment: You would have to treat the surroundings as a separate system and you would have to solve the transient partial differential momentum balance and heat transfer equations for the entire process for both the system and surroundings.  This would include viscous effects and heat conduction/convection effects.  In most cases, it is not possible to apply equilibrium thermodynamics to an irreversible process.